# Sniffing traffic at embedded linux

Tags: linux, embedded, http

Are there any sniffers out there? I'm looking for something that can be compiled for an embedded device.

**Important**: I'm not limited in space. Therefore it can be any-size sniffer that can be compiled for armv7 and run at embedded Linux

Comment: Not knowing much about your embedded environment, but the standard `tcpdump` should be compilable. It works on Rasperry Pi's, which are ARM (some even ARM7). Even the standard `wireshark` should be doable. I cannot see the problem.

Comment: Embedded Linux don't have these two commands

Comment: You asked " something that can be compiled" for ARM. `tcpdump` can be compiled for ARM. The fact that it is currently not in your repository does not alter that fact.